# How to manually request event from Observable?

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, observable, rx-android

I'm using `RxJava` and `Retrofit` to create an app and I have this scenario that inside my view a list of items is loaded from the server and displayed to the user. The user is able to refresh the data by clicking a refresh button. The following is a rough implementation of my scenario using MVP.

```
// This is my retrofit adapter service
public interface ApiService{
    @GET("items");
    Observable<JsonElement> getItemsList();
}

// This is my presnter
public class MyPresnter{
    ...
    public Observable<List<Item>> loadItemsList(){
        return apiService.getItemsList().map(jsonElement -> {
            // here I convert my api response to a List of Items
            return new ArrayList<Item>();
        });
    }
}

// And inside my view I use RxBinding to bind my button click events
RxView.clicks(refreshBtn).subscribe(view -> mPresenter.loadItemsList()
                                            .subscribeOn(Schdulers.io())
                                            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                                            .subscribe(list -> {/* update view */})
                                   );
```

Now my question is how should I request data without clicking the `refreshBtn` for example when the user first enters the view? Should I use `refreshBtn.performOnClick()`?
Or is there a way to manually request event on an already subscribed observable?

Comment: I understand why you'd like to use RxJava here (I too was obsessed with using it everywhere after learning about it), but your use case probably does not need reactive approach at all. Just do it the way you would go about AsyncTask: declare a `Subscription` property in your screen, assign it to result of `Observable#subscribe` when you are subscribing and null it out when the background operation completes. Note, that RxJava classes have a lot of overhead, so using methods like `RxView.clicks` the way you do (without actually chaining them with other operators) is pretty bad idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer this, we need to question the logic of the stream. It is generally *bad practice* to subscribe to a new observable in a subscribe method of a previous one. There might be cases where there might not be a better way around but it is at least an indication to investigate. Composition of streams is one of the greatest advantages RxJava has.

The logic here suggests that there is a series of events ( clicks and manual invocation) , to which you want to react with subscribing to another stream. There is an operator which has this exact behavior called `flatMap`.

Thanks to `flatMap` operator, we already have means to react whenever ***something*** happens:

```
refreshEventStream
    .flatMap(object -> {
        return mPresenter.loadItemsList().subscribeOn(Schdulers.io())
    })
    .subscribe(list -> /* update UI */)
```

Now, we need to figure out what ***something*** actually represents. As you described, there are currently 2 ways to invoke the refresh. Through a click event and manual refresh. In other words, we want to ***merge*** those events into one stream. Again, there is a nice and shiny operator called `mergeWith` which we can use. However, for manual invocation we need to create Subject ( http://reactivex.io/documentation/subject.html ), which acts both like an Observable and a Subscriber.

```
 PublishSubject<Void> refreshSubject = PublishSubject.create()
 refreshEventStream = refreshSubject
                          .mergeWith(Rx.clicks(refreshBtn).throttleFirst(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))

 refreshEventStream
    .flatMap(object -> {
        return mPresenter.loadItemsList().subscribeOn(Schdulers.io())
    })
    .subscribe(list -> /* update UI */)
```

I added `throttleFirst` operator to the click stream, as you probably don't want to let user spam with requests like this :-) The only thing it does is that it takes an event from that stream and ignores the rest of the emissions for specified amount of time before reacting to it again.

Comment: Thanks for this amazing answer. This is why I'm falling for RxJava! Cheers. ;)

Answer (score 3):

I guess you could call `performOnClick` provided you have setup the `RxView.clicks()` beforehand.

Generally, you may want to merge in a `Subject` that can also trigger the operations:

```
PublishSubject<Object> manualRefresh = PublishSubject.create();

RxView.clicks(refreshBtn)
.cast(Object.class)
.mergeWith(manualRefresh.onBackpressureLatest())
.switchMap(v -> mPresenter.loadItemsList()
                .subscribeOn(Schdulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
)
.subscribe(list -> /* update */);

manualRefresh.onNext("Now!");
```